# Folder Redirection Creates New, Local Folder

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7

We have folder redirection setup for an already existing infrastructure.  When we turn on the redirection for clients that already have data they get redirected to the server but also get copied to a folder on `C:\Users\%Username%\OldFiles`.  The problem is they are not always copied to the `OldFiles` folder, sometimes they are just moved.  It appears to be random but I cannot tell.

Is this normal behavior for folder redirection? I have looked for ages, all over Microsoft and they never mention it.

Thanks!

Comment: 1. Saying that you have folder redirection setup doesn't mean a whole lot considering there are a number of folders that can be redirected. Presumably you mean that you are redirecting the Documents folder? 2. What exactly is the problem, if the folders are being redirected to the server then why is it a problem whether or not they get copied to OldFiles?

Comment: Yes, I am redirecting Documents, Pictures, Desktop, and AppData.  The only real problem with the OldFiles is that sometimes it is not a copy and it is a move, so the files basically get lost in the OldFiles folder.  But, if this is normal practice then there may be something I can do to stop it from creating this folder all together.